# Magnetic charge of 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole

Tags: gauge-theory, topology, yang-mills, magnetic-monopoles

In "Quantum Field Theory", Srednicki defines the magnetic field in $SU(2)$ gauge theory as
$$B^i= \epsilon^{ijk}\partial_j\left(\hat{\varphi}^a A_k^a \right)-\dfrac{1}{2e} \varepsilon^{ijk} \varepsilon^{abc} \hat{\varphi}^a \partial_j \hat{\varphi}^b \partial_k \hat{\varphi}^c,\tag{92.41}$$
and the winding number as
$$n=\frac{1}{8 \pi} \int d^{2} \theta \, \varepsilon^{a b c} \varepsilon^{i j} \hat{\varphi}^{a} \partial_{i} \hat{\varphi}^{b} \partial_{j} \hat{\varphi}^{c}, \tag{92.35}$$
with $d^{2} \theta=d \theta d \phi, \partial_{1}=\partial / \partial \theta, \partial_{2}=\partial / \partial \phi$, and $\varepsilon^{12}=-\varepsilon^{21}=+1$.

When integrating the magnetic field through a sphere at infinity, I can see why the first term vanishes. However, I am not able to see how Srednicki concludes (he states the answer) that
$$\Phi\equiv \int d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{B},$$
with $dS_k=r^2 \sin\theta\, d\theta \, d\phi\, \dfrac{x^k}{r}$, amounts to $$\Phi=-\dfrac{4\pi n}{e}.\tag{92.42}$$ It seems fairly easy just looking at the definition of $n$, but I haven't been able to reconcile the result with it. Is there something I'm missing?